# How can give rights to users for individual activity in workflow based on user login..?

Tags: security, user-management, user-rights

I have created the Workflow and in each activity I given the diffrent user groups so that only those users can do activities which are assigend to respective user groups. I did the same (created 3 users groups and assigned the 3 diffrent users, which are not system administrator in tridion and also assigned the workflow management rights to all user groups in the specific publication where I need to implement workflow so that one user will do the activity for creation, other one will do the approval of component and last one wil ldo the publication approval).

Above is the required senario which i need to implement, but issue is that all users(login in diffrent browsers with diffrent users id) are able to see all activity and can perform the task which are not assigned to them.

Sometimes user tried to approved the activity which is assigned to other users and in that case user get the error in the tridion but activity get happened.

Need help to resolve above issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not give these user groups Workflow Management Rights. Also, make sure that these groups are independent (they all may be members of Authors group, for example).

Comment: If I will not give the workflow management rights then how these users will do the approval activities, and all user groups are created by me and all are independent.

Comment: Workflow management right is only needed to manage workflow processes, it's not necessary to take part in workflow process. Users can still start \ finish appropriate activities

Comment: Oh Great, its working. there were also few access issues.

Comment: I'd guess "access issues" meant the users were part of the same group? Unless there are *only* three users, it's probably a good idea to assign activities to separate groups rather than individuals.